# Spark and events correlations

Tags: events, apache-spark, spark-streaming, complex-event-processing

I am currently studying if Spark can help for improving the scalability and fail-over on a component in my system, but I am not really used to the notion of this library.

A simple use case I have to address:

1. I receive events (through various endpoint, like
   syslog/relp/database..)
2. If an event is "semantically equivalent" to an old event, in a time window (from 1h, to 24h), then the new event should be associated with the old event, and data on the old event should be updated (some severities, causes, etc)
3. Events are then sent to an ElasticSearch cluster

The latency of this system should be low: if I receive an event, it should be in the database in less than X seconds. Moreover, the rules evaluating the "semantic" of an event can be updated without stopping the stream of events.

Currently, I use a simple strategy: Events are just stored in memory (through hazelcast), but only one node can correlate events between them. It's not really scalable neither fault-tolerant.

It looks like joining stream can help with this kind of thing, but I lake concretes examples...

Can Spark handle this use case, while being scalable & fault tolerant? I am looking for some pointers about stream correlation while being fault tolerant with Spark (doc ? example ?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to use Spark Streaming.

One possibility to do this in Spark might be to introduce a state by using the updateStateByKey function, which means actually implementing a state. 
You find the description in the official docu and here is an [example](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html).

Another possibility might be using the built-in windowing functions in Spark Streaming. Again check out the official docu.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using logstash and elasticsearch. In your logstash configuration you could monitor your unique identification for any event and based on that make queries to the elasticsearch. It will list all the related events in one search.